# Evaluate integral over triangle with stokes' theorem

Tags: calculus, integration, multiple-integral, stokes-theorem

The sides of a triangle $D$ are described by the intersections of plane $x + 3y + 4z = 6$ with the planes $x = 0, y = 0 $ and $z = 0$.
 
Determine the integral over the triangle $D$ using Stokes' theorem.

$\int_{\partial D}^{} \! -2y^2 dx+zdy +x dz \, =$

My question:

I know that Stokes' theorem is defined as $\int_{C}^{} \! F\cdot ds \, =\int_{}^{} \! \int_{S}^{} \! (\nabla \times F) \,   \, ds   $. But I dont understand what excatly is $F$ in my example?

Comment: $F=\langle -2y^2, z, x\rangle$

Answer (score 1):

Let me rewrite Stokes' theorem as

$$ \int_{D} \boldsymbol{\nabla \times F \cdot dS} = \oint_{\partial D} \boldsymbol{F \cdot dr}.  $$

In your case,

$$\boldsymbol{F \cdot dr} = -2y^2 dx + z dy + x dz = (-2y^2, z, x) \cdot (dx, dy, dz) $$

so $\boldsymbol{F}(x,y,z) = (-2y^2, z, x)$. Thus, in order to solve the question, you need to calculate $\boldsymbol{\nabla \times F}$ and then perform the surface integral of $\boldsymbol{\nabla \times F}$ over the (two-dimensional) triangle $D$.

Comment: I calculated that: $\nabla \times F=(-1,-1,4y)$. After that I found gradient of $2x+3y+4z-6=0$ and I got $(-2,3,4)$. I did multiplication $(\nabla \times F) \cdot ds=(2-3+16y)$ Can you say me is this good and if yes how to determine boundaries of integral? Can I just put that $z=0$ and express $y$ with $x$?

Comment: In the question you wrote that the plane is $x + 3y + 4z = 6$ while in the comment you have considered $2x + 3y + 4z = 6$. Which is it? In any case, the normal to the plane in the original question is $\pm \frac{(1,3,4)}{\sqrt{1^2 + 3^2 + 4^2}} = \pm \frac{(1,3,4)}{\sqrt{26}}$. To determine the boundaries of the integral you can indeed project the triangle to the $xy$ plane (put $z = 0$) and express $z$ with $x,y$.

Comment: It is $2x$. I made mistake in question, but nevermind. Should I then multiply normal to the plane with the result of cross product $(\nabla \times F)$ or? I am not sure what is my integral now.

Comment: You need to describe the triangle $D$ by a parametrization $u \colon D' \rightarrow D$ where $D' \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$. Then the integral you are calculating is $\int_{D'} \mathbf{F}(u(x,y)) \cdot \frac{(2,3,4)}{\sqrt{29}} \, dx dy$.